# Jquery Datatables uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I put it in the variable already but it still gives me an error and it says uncaught reference error oTable is not defined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
          success: function( result ) {
          var oTable = $("#datatable").DataTable({
                processing: true,
                data: result,
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id'},
                    {data: 'title'}
                ]
            });
          }
        });
    });
    $("#reload").click(function(){
        oTable.DataTable().ajax.reload();
    });

});
</script>
```

here is my html

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>TITLE</th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

please help me Thanks

Comment: otable have the scope only inside the click function.. try removing the “var” from “var oTable”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work for you

Use Datatable Method to Load ajax,

No need to Initiate again to reload Datatble  use `oTable.ajax.reload()`;

I changed `oTable` to Global variable

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#reload").click(function () {
                oTable.ajax.reload();
            });
            $("#test").click(function () {
                window.oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
                        "dataSrc": ""
                    },
                    "columns": [{
                            "data": "id"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "title"
                        },

                    ]
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       
      
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <button id="reload">
    reaload 
    </button>
    <button id="test">
    test 
    </button>

    <div class="container">
        <table id="datatable">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>TITLE</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>


        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your oTable variable definition was on onSuccess callback, so it can't call from outside of onSuccess callback scope

Comment: perhaps you could add some code to your answer to illustrate your thought better